# How to pass class name as variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I have foo.rb and main.rb files which was created by another file.

foo.rb:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
   @val = 1
  end
end
```

main.rb:

```
file_name = gets.chomp()
require_relative(file_name)
class_name = file_name.capitalize
a = class_name.new()
p "This is val: #{a.val}"
```

But I get an error: `undefined method`new' for "Foo.rb":String (NoMethodError)`

My question: How can I pass class name as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the extension...

```
class_name = Object.const_get(file_name.capitalize[/^[^.]*/])
```

Comment: You don't need *regexp*... :-) I mean, we have a method for that.

Comment: you mark it as duplicate yet you are providing an answer